# Javascript regex OR operator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to combine two separate regex queries into one default one in a small script I have.

The first query is

```
/\[(.*?)\]/g
```

Which matches shortcodes like this

```
[gallery]
```

The second query is

```
/\[([^\]]+)]([^\[]+)\[\/([^\]]+)]/g
```

Which matches shortcodes like this

```
[gallery]data[/gallery]
```

When I try to combine the queries, like this

```
/\[(.*?)\]|\[([^\]]+)]([^\[]+)\[\/([^\]]+)]/g
```

Everything is matched **except** the "data" inside an extended shortcode, like this.

```
[gallery]
[gallery][/gallery]
```

The result I am expecting / wanting to see is this

```
[gallery]
[gallery]data[/gallery]
```

Comment: Why not use two regex?

Comment: I have successfully used two regex's separately, but it would be tidier to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just reverse the patterns.** Because the order of matching is something like that the regex you gave first(ie, *regex which was present just before to the OR `|` operator*) would do the matching operation and next comes the second regex. You gave  `\[(.*?)\]` as first regex so it matches also the strings that must be matched by the second regex. Reversing the order would force the regex engine to match strings like this `[gallery]data[/gallery]` on very first. After that the strings like this `[gallery]` would be matched.

```
\[([^\]]+)]([^\[]+)\[\/([^\]]+)]|\[(.*?)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kB8pY9/7)

Comment: Thanks for the fast contribution - problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  \[([^\]]+)]([^\[]+)\[\/([^\]]+)]|\[(.*?)\]
```

Try this.The bigger first.

See Demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tK9sJ3/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\[(.*?)\](?:([^\[]+)\[\/([^\]]+)])?
```

Answer (score 0):

just simple try:

```
/\[[^\]]+]([^\[]+\[\/[^\]]+])?/g
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/MHN4FbDM-rmtKHjf)

Answer (score 0):

Using an optional non-capturing group, and a backreference to the first match:

```
/\[(.+?)\](?:([^\]]+)\[\/\1\])?/g
```